# crystal report and avery 5160 in vb

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports-2010

I created a avery 5160 report in Crystal Reports through the wizard.  When I pass my values to Crystal it is only showing 1 label in the report viewer.

1. Do I have to tell Crystal I want 30 of these to print on one page in code?
2. Is there a way to check my settings after the wizard completes?

Here is my report code:

```
Dim report As New Avery5160()

Dim ds As DataSet = New DataSet
Dim dt = New CrystalDS.DataTable1DataTable()
ds.Tables.Add(dt)

report.SetDataSource(ds)

dt.Rows.Add(bmpBytes)
report.SetParameterValue(0, Desc)
report.SetParameterValue(1, WriteUPC)
CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = report
CrystalReportViewer1.Refresh()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure it out by creating a loop to add the item 30 times to the report.

```
    For i = 0 To 29
        dt.Rows.Add(bmpBytes)
        report.SetParameterValue(0, Desc)
        report.SetParameterValue(1, WriteUPC)
    Next
```